# regexp_substr for getting correct result

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I was trying to use regexp_substr to get each correct column name from a column list string.

The query is like:

```
select regexp_substr(v_keep, '(^|[(,) ]*)' || r.column_name || '($|[(,) ]+)', 1, 1, 'i')
from dual;
```

But the result is not correct.

The v_keep can be any column name list like abc, abc_abc, abc1 or (abc, abc_abc, abc1).

The r.column_name can be like abc or ab.

**- If the input v_keep is (abc, abc_abc, abc1) and the r.column_name is
   ab, it will return null.**

**- If the input v_keep is (abc, abc_abc, abc1) and the r.column_name is 
   abc, it will return the column name just abc.**

Can anyone help me to fix it by just modify the pattern inside the regexp_substr ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a `case` and `like`?

```
select (case when replace(replace(v_keep, '(', ','), '(', ',')) like '%,' || r.column_name || ',%'
             then r.column_name
        end)
```

I don't recommend storing lists in a comma-delimited string, but if you are, this is one way to identify individual elements of the list.

Comment: Because this query is part of code in a if condition, I'm new to oracle, I have no idea how to implement case in that code.

Comment: @infi999 . . . I have no idea what you mean.  The code in the question is in the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, you just need to add a subexpression so you can pull out the part of the string you want. (A subexpression is a section of the regexp in parentheses.) In this case the last argument is 2, because you want the part of the match that corresponds to the second group of parentheses.

```
regexp_substr(v_keep, '(^|[(,) ]*)(' || r.column_name || ')($|[(,) ]+)', 1, 1, 'i', 2)
```

Gordon's solution will have better performance, though.

Edit: working example -

```
with testdata as (select '(abc, abc_abc, abc1)' as v_keep, 'abc' as column_name from dual)
select regexp_substr(v_keep, '(^|[(,) ]*)(' || r.column_name || ')($|[(,) ]+)', 1, 1, 'i', 2)
from testdata r;
```

Comment: I got the idea to do that. I try to replace the brackets and space to comma, then I use  instr(v_keep1, ',' || r.column_name || ',') > 0 to check if the current name is in the list. This performance should be better than use regex. But still thanks you all!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is PL/SQL code to see if a value is in a string, try this which avoids the overhead of hitting the database, and calling REGEXP.  Just keep it straight SQL. I hate the nested REPLACE calls but I was trying to avoid using REGEXP_REPLACE although it could be done in one call if you did use it.

```
set serveroutput on;
set feedback off;

declare 
  v_keep  varchar2(50) := '(abc, abc_abc, abc1)';
  compare varchar2(10) := 'abc_';
begin
  if instr(',' || replace(replace(replace(v_keep, ' '), '('), ')') || ',', ',' || compare || ',') > 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('Column ''' || compare ||''' IS in the keep list');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('Column ''' || compare ||''' IS NOT in the keep list');
  end if;  
end;
```